# Creting a table in SQL 1 Error code. 1241

Tags: mysql

Having some trouble creating a table in MySQL. I dont seem to understand what is the mistake that I am making. Here is the code that I have.

```
create table customerDim(
    CustomerID int not null auto_increment primary key,
    FirstName varchar(30) not null, 
    LastName varchar(30) not null, 
    Gender char(1) not null,
    Street1 varchar(100) not null,
    Street2 varchar(100) null,
    City varchar(30) not null,
    StateAbbrev char(2) not null,
    Zipcode char(5) not null, 
    PrimaryPhone varchar(10) not null,
    EmailAddress varchar(50) null,
    constraint GenderCheck check (Gender in ('F','M')),
    constraint ZipCheck check (Zipcode NOT LIKE ('%[0-9]%',5)),
    constraint PhoneCheck check (PrimaryPhone NOT LIKE ('%[0-9]%',10)),
    constraint PhoneCheck2 check(LENGTH(PrimaryPhone)=10)
    );
```

Getting Error Code: 241. Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Comment: What are 5 and 10 after your oatterns in like and not like?

Comment: The `LIKE` operator expect one string argument, you provide some kind of list with `('%[0-9]%',5)`. Where do you have this syntax from?

Comment: Omg that is SQL Server syntax. I took them out and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: In MySQL use `Zipcode RLIKE '^[0-9]{5}$'`